# Use Jenkins to run Jasmine tests and give coverage to Sonarqube

Tags: angular, typescript, jenkins, continuous-integration

We are using Jenkins for CI and SonarQube for Code Quality. As a Web framework we are using Angular (4). The Problem is that our Jenkins can build our project, but can not run the jasmine-tests. I tried some things, but nothing worked. I want Jenkins to run our tests and give the coverage data to sonarqube. Is there anyone who can explain how to configure the project and jenkins to do this or maybe a link to a tutorial.

This is our karma.conf.js at the moment

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
            require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
            require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma'),
            require('karma-junit-reporter'),
            require('karma-mocha-reporter')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
        reporters: ['mocha', 'junit'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
        singleRun: true,

        junitReporter: {
            outputDir: 'build/test-results/karma',
            outputFile: 'karma-test.xml',
            useBrowserName: true
        },
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use docker container to run your tests.
There are a lot of resources about this like:

1. https://hackernoon.com/running-karma-tests-with-headless-chrome-inside-docker-ae4aceb06ed3
2. https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+build+step+plugin